# Django Forms: How to add icons instead or in addition to the form fields

Tags: django, django-forms

Given that we live in the emjoi era, you may want to have a form to ask for user input using icons.  Say for example, you want to find out which sport the user prefers.  Instead of or in addition to the text, you may want to display the icon for the choice (e.g. showing a basketball for basketball choice).

How do you go about this in Django in an automated way.  I understand that I can manually render each field and add HTML to it, but that's more hacking your way through.  What if I want to render so many fields in a formset with so many choices for each field of each form using a for loop in the template and do not look forward to manually going through the fields and add the icon for each field of each form.

Answer (score 0):

This awesome (pun intended) [package](https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-fontawesome/) does it all. And you can build on it's IconField if you need different icons.